# web deploy causing bad image exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web application that uses an unmanaged 32 bit dll that I have successfully running on my development machine, but when I use web deploy to move the code to our test server, I start seeing BadImageFormat exceptions.

I set the target in visual web developer to x86 and both machines are running 64 bit os's (windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2).  I'm not sure what other differences there could be causing the problem.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there was a flag "Enable 32-bit executables" or something like this in the config files for the webserver that starts out false under iis 7.5

The error message was a total red herring.